# On the multiplicity of the second largest eigenvalue of adjacency matrix

Tags: graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, adjacency-matrix

Let $G$ be a connected, finite, simple, undirected and vertex-transitive graph with $N$ vertices.
Denote by $\mu_0> \mu_1\geq \dots \geq\mu_{N-1}$ all eigenvalues of the adjacency matrix associated with $G$.

My question is:

Does there exist $G$ such that the multiplicity of $\mu_1$ is strictly greater than $1$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are many examples of vertex-transitive graphs whose multiplicity of $\mu_1$ is strictly greater than $1$.

- Complete graph $K_n$ for $n \ge 3$ has spectrum $(n-1)^1,(-1)^{n-1}$.
- Complete bipartite graphs $K_{n,n}$ for $n \ge 2$ has spectrum $\pm n, 0^{2n-2}$.
- Cycles

  - $C_3 = K_3$  has spectrum $2, (-1)^2$
  - $C_4 = K_{2,2}$  has spectrum $2, 0^2, -2$.
  - $C_5$ has spectrum $2, (\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^2, (\frac{-1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^2$.
  - $C_6$ has spectrum $2, 1^2, (-1)^2, -2$.
  - For other $n > 6$, $C_n$ has spectrum $$2, (2\cos\frac{2\pi}{n})^2, (2\cos\frac{4\pi}{n})^2, \ldots$$
    All multiplicities are $2$, expect that of $\mu_0 = 2$ or 
    $\mu_{n-1} = -2$ when $n$ is odd.
- The $n$-cube graph $Q_n$ ($1$-skeleton of the hypercube $[0,1]^n$) for $n \ge 2$ has spectrum $$n^1, (n-2)^{\binom{n}{1}}, (n-4)^{\binom{n}{2}},\ldots$$
- Platonic graphs - the multiplicity of $\mu_1$ for all five platonic graphs is $3$.

  - The tetrahedral graph is isomorphic to $K_4$, it has spectrum $3^1 (-1)^3$.
  - The cubical graph is isomorphic to $Q_3$, it has spectrum $3^1,1^3,(-1)^3,(-3)^1$.
  - The octahedral graph has spectrum $4^1, 0^3, (-2)^2$.
  - The icosahedral graph has spectrum $5^1,(\sqrt{5})^3, (-1)^5, (-\sqrt{5})^3$.
  - The dodecahedral graph has spectrum $3^1,(\sqrt{5})^3, 1^5, 0^4, (-2)^4, (-\sqrt{5})^3$.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer.
How about the existence of a vertex-transitive graph with simple $\mu_1$ ?

Comment: @Nick, no idea. I try to lookup the spectrum of other obvious vertex-transitive graphs (more precisely, the 1-skeleton of all semi-regular polytopes), it turns out none of them has a simple $\mu_1$.

Comment: @Nick oops, there is one trivial example for simple $\mu_1$. $P_2$. the path graph with 2 vertices has spectrum $1,-1$.

Comment: I tried to construct a large v-transitive graph with simple $\mu_1$, but I could not. Thank you.